# can't enable physics Debug Draw mode

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-physics

i'm using `cocos2dx 3.3` and i `setDebugDrawMask` looks like below

```
scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
```

But nothing draw on my screen evenif there has many boxes.

Comment: you also need to set your sprites and images visibly false then only you can see it .

Comment: i have set my sprites and images visibly false, but nothing draw, i test many example code but it still not draw debug
Example code: https://github.com/SonarSystems/Cocos2d-x-C---Physics-Tutorial-13---Custom-Physics-Bodies

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code snippet for drawing debugNode for physics space. However it is written in js for Cocos2d-x-js, I hope it will help.

```
function initDebugMode(controller) {
    var phDebugNode = cc.PhysicsDebugNode.create(space);
    controller.addChild(phDebugNode, 10);
}
```

Comment: no problem :) vote for my answer please or select it as an answer for question, kind regards :)

Answer (score 0):

create your scene using below code

```
auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
```

then go ahead and add features to your scene
scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);

Hope this helps